# What is the purpose of using Log class in android?

Tags: android

I read the class in android docs but I didn't get what is the purpose of using Log class in our code.
I know the various Log methods Like Log.i(), Log.e(), Log.v() etc, but why do we use this class?

Comment: I've already read this, I that link Log methods are elaborated that why where we use Log.e(), Log.i(), etc but the purpose of using this is not mentioned.

Comment: I'm reopening this.  He's not asking what those functions mean, but why to use logging at all.  A bad question to have to be asking, but a different one.

Comment: you should also read the answers, nobody has commented on why these Logs are used :-/

Answer (score 1):

To write data to the Android log file for debugging.  You might put a log statement in a rare corner case to output a message so you know it happened.  Or you may put a lot of log cases in the code so you can debug an issue without stepping through in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I will just give a link from another StackExchange network site :

[Logging : Why and What](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37294/logging-why-and-what)

A clean and clear part :

> There are two reasons logging is performed:
>
> - Diagnostic
> - Audit

You should read all the answers to have more details.